# Material UI Select - object as value fails

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

in my app I'm using Material UI an React. I created a Select dropdown in order to change the displayed values. So when I change the selection, the data on the page should be updated. Unfortunately, I can't add my object to the value property of the MenuItem. In CodeSandbox it is working with an underlined value, but not in my local environment.

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/select-exmpl-iosfg

Local error:
[image]

Comment: Can you please try to replace the line 96, the line where the error is pointing with <MenuItem key={value}>{value.modelName}</MenuItem> and see. Also, consider wrapping your MenuItem around a Menu tag. You will find some examples here https://material-ui.com/components/menus/.

Comment: @SubhayuGhosh: Thanks for your response. This leads to the following error: Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `.$.$.$[object Object]`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Comment: sorry my bad please try key={value.modelName} instead

Comment: After changing it, nothing works anymore.

Comment: Did you wrap it like so? `import MenuList from '@material-ui/core/MenuList';`
`<MenuList> <MenuItem key={value.modelName}>{value.modelName}</MenuItem> </MenuList>`

Comment: Yes, it's not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231774/discussion-between-subhayu-ghosh-and-mapof).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed on chat, this should work.

```
<Select
  value={plant}
  onChange={handleSelectChange}
  defaultValue={plant}
  displayEmpty
>
  {plants.map((tmpPlant) => (
    //@ts-ignore - necessary to load object into value
    <MenuItem value={tmpPlant}>{tmpPlant.id}</MenuItem>
  ))}
</Select>;
```

Additionally, it is a good idea to add a key prop to the map function within the MenuItem like so `key={tmpPlant.id}`

Comment: I implemented with similar approach and I was just curious If it was legit. thanks for sharing! I found that in the browser's dev tools, li element has a data-value which stores "Object Object". I suppose it is for the internal working of Select component. any thoughts?